# Почему невозможно засэтить margin для yandex карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как сделать чтобы отступы margin-bottom был динамический? Возможно ли прописать это в Yandex API ? Или как можно написать другой скрипт чтобы решить данный вопрос ?

Добавил карту на страницу однако их высота меняется так как `ymaps` генерирует разные классы, его класс автоматически автоинкрементится `ymaps-2-1-60-map` и значение в ном `ymaps-2-1-60-map` добавляется на 1, что будет `ymaps-2-1-61-map`

У меня на сайте 3 карты, прописал единственный скрипт js, самый простой.

```
//Show map on the web page

ymaps.ready(init);

function init(){
    var myMap,
        myPlacemark,
        myMap2,
        myPlacemark2,
        myMap3,
        myPlacemark3;

    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [43.24226231, 76.89127236],
        zoom: 17
    });

    myMap.controls
        .remove('rulerControl')
        .remove('searchControl');

    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([43.24224271, 76.89130991], { 
        balloonContentHeader: 'Valesco',
        balloonContentBody: 'ул. Шевченко 204 ТД «Саламат-1» 4-ый этаж',
        balloonContentFooter: 'Это наш адрес',
        hintContent: 'Это наш адрес'
     });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

    myMap2 = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [51.11553962, 71.42805238],
        zoom: 17
    });

    myMap2.controls
        .remove('rulerControl')
        .remove('searchControl');

    myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([51.11543833, 71.42808457], { 
        balloonContentHeader: 'Valesco',
        balloonContentBody: 'Есильский район, улица Туркестан 8 ВП-20',
        balloonContentFooter: 'Это наш адрес',
        hintContent: 'Это наш адрес'
     });

    myMap2.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);

    myMap3 = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [43.63220479, 51.17577490],
        zoom: 17
    });

    myMap3.controls
        .remove('rulerControl')
        .remove('searchControl');

    myPlacemark3 = new ymaps.Placemark([43.63209388, 51.17577490], { 
        balloonContentHeader: 'Valesco',
        balloonContentBody: '1 микрорайон ТЦ СтройМарт 2 этаж, бутик “Parador”',
        balloonContentFooter: 'Это наш адрес',
        hintContent: 'Это наш адрес'
     });

    myMap3.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark3);
```

}

CSS прописан только для одного статического значения, поэтому нижние отступы у карты меняются

```
#main-contacts ymaps.ymaps-2-1-60-map:nth-child(1), #main-contacts ymaps.ymaps-2-1-60-map:nth-child(2){
    margin-bottom: 119px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Переопределять css-классы API, как в Вашем примере нельзя. Во-первых, это действительно сломается с выходом новой версии, а во-вторых, может непредсказуемо сломать что-то другое в работе карты.

В API Яндекс.Карт есть [менеджер отступов](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/map.margin.Manager-docpage/?from=SO). Он позволяет задать прямоугольные области в экранных координатах, которые обозначают занятые области контейнера карты.

[Пример в песочнице Яндекса](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/margin_manager?from=SO)